# Impact of more executors than cpu/cores in Storm Cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-storm

I have started using Apache Storm recently. Right now focusing on some performance testing and tuning for one of my applications (pulls data from a NoSQL database, formats, and publishes to a JMS Queue for consumption by the requester) to enable more parallel request processing at a time. I have been able to tune the topology in terms of changing no. of bolts, MAX_SPENDING_SPOUT etc. and to throttle data flow within topology using some ticking approach.

I wanted to know what happens when we define more parallelism than the no of cores we have. In my case I have a single node, single worker topology and the machine has 32 cores. But total no of executors (for all the spouts and bolts) = 60. So my questions are:

1. Does this high number really helps processing requests or is it actually degrades the performance, since I believe there will more context switch between bolt tasks to utilize cores.
2. If I define 20 (just a random selection) executors for a Bolt and my code flow never needs to utilize the Bolt, will this be impacting performance? How does storm handles this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, so the answer is (as always): it depends.

If your load is large and a single executor fully utilizes a core completely, having more executors cannot give you any throughput improvements. If there is any impact, it might be negative (also with regard to contention of internally used queues to which all executers need to read from and write into for tuple transfer).

If you load is "small" and does not fully utilize your CPUs, it wound matter either -- you would not gain or loose anything -- as your cores are not fully utilized you have some left over head room anyway.

Furthermore, consider that Storm spans some more threads within each worker. Thus, if your executors fully utilize your hardware, those thread will also be impacted.

Overall, you should not run your topologies to utilize core completely anyway but leave form head room for small "spikes" etc. In operation, maybe 80% CPU utilization might be a good value. As a rule of thumb, one executor per core should be ok.